# Weird polymorphism behavior with multiple inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, sdl, multiple-inheritance

So, I'm writing on a little Pong game clone using SDL and I have the following setup.

There's a general game class `SlimGame` which inherits from an FSM class and an event handler class:

```
// DEFINITION
class SlimGame : public SlimFSM, public SlimEventHandler {
protected:
  bool    running;        // indicates if the game is running

public:
  bool isRunning() { return this->running; }
  void setRunning(bool r) { this->running = r; }

  void run();                         // encapsulates the game loop
};

// IMPLEMENTATION
void SlimGame::run() {
  SDL_Event event;

  this->setRunning(true);

  while(this->isRunning()) {
      while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
          this->handleEvent(&event);
          std::cout << "MAIN LOOP Running: " << this->isRunning(); << endl;
      }

      // ...
  }
}
```

The FSM class is irrelevant to the weird behavior, but the event handler class looks like this:

```
// DEFINITION
class SlimEventHandler {
public:
  SlimEventHandler() { }
  virtual ~SlimEventHandler() { }

  void handleEvent(SDL_Event *event);

  virtual void onExit();
};

// IMPLEMENTATION
void SlimEventHandler::handleEvent(SDL_Event *event) {
  switch(event->type) {
    case SDL_QUIT:
      this->onExit();
      break;
  }
}

void SlimEventHandler::onExit() {
  std::cout << "PARENT onExit!" << std::endl;
}
```

And then I have my `PongGame` class itself which inherits from `SlimGame` (and therefore indirectly from `SlimFSM` and `SlimEventHandler`):

```
// DEFINITION
class PongGame : public SlimGame {
public:
  PongGame();
  ~PongGame();

  void onExit();
};

// IMPLEMENTATION
void PongGame::onExit() {
  this->setRunning(false);

  std::cout << "CHILD onExit!" << std::endl;
}
```

So with this setup I run my game like this and it starts up, nicely:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  PongGame game;

  // setup

  game.run();

  // tear down

  return 0;
}
```

However the event handling doesn't work the way it's supposed to work. If I click the window closing button the `SDL_QUIT` event get's fired and the method `handleEvent` gets called. This is fine, but the method itself calls `onExit` of its own, not the inherited method of the `PongGame` class, so I see:

```
PARENT onExit!
```

in the console instead of

```
CHILD onExit!
```

Shouldn't the derived method in `PongGame` be called, instead of the virtual empty implementation in `SlimEventHandler`?

Comment: I stubbed in some classes to get your code to compile and I do see "CHILD onExit", so it seems like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Interesting. Could it be an issue of having the code split up in libraries? I'm working on Mac OSX and everything except the `PongGame` class is in a static library...

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I moved my `run` method into the `PongGame` class and now it's working, which is good, but not the level of abstraction I'd like to have... very, very strange!

Comment: Try making the SlimEventHandler::onExit() be pure virtual.  That may cause a compile error that would make the problem more obvious.

Comment: No compile error, but at running the program crashes with: `libc++abi.dylib: pure virtual method called`

Comment: What's also very, very weird: the `running` member variable that's has a different value in `PongGame::onExit` and in `SlimGame::onExit`! It looks like I'm not having an instance of `PongGame` but of `SlimGame` -> this is getting weirder and weirder...

Comment: `pure virtual method called` is typically a symptom of calling virtual functions inside a constructor or destructor, but may also be due to calling methods of an object that has been deleted.

Comment: Check your backtrace when it crashes and see if you are in a constructor or destructor.

Comment: No, I am where I am supposed to be. No constructer, no destructer. I am in `SlimEventHandler::handleEvent()` but `this` shows to be an instance of `SlimGame` not `PongGame`...

Comment: Try printing out `this` inside SlimGame and PongGame constructors.  See if you get more than one of each.

Comment: Nope. Each constructer is only called once, and `this` is the same address... this is ridiculous :)

Comment: Print out `this` in SlimEventHandler::handleEvent() also.

Comment: Okay. Now we're getting somewhere. `this` in the constructor of `SlimEventHandler` is different than in `SlimGame` and `PongGame` and `SlimFSM` --> ?

Comment: That is to be expected.  It is the second base so it will have a non-zero offset from the beginning of the SlimGame object.

Comment: It is generally impossible to debug a C++ program without seeing the source in its entirety. A bug in one place can lead to weird behaviour in seemingly unrelated places. Try to come up with a minimal self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Just to make sure: SlimFSM does not declare onExit() method and does not inherit from any class that does?

Comment: Double checked and no... But interestingly if I remove `SlimFSM` from the inheritance it's working, so there's gotta be the problem somewhere in there...

Comment: another wild guess: does SlimFSM overload operator-> ?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't... `SlimFSM` also has no virtual methods, or so. Standard class implementation.

Comment: Did you try to add virtual destructor into SlimGame class? Does it works then?

Comment: There is a virtual constructer in SlimGame, yes. Still doesn't work... But I went another way, anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Vapire you should consider answering your own question if you found the problem so others can benefit from it

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found the problem, I just went in another direction...

Comment: I've seen weird stuff like this when linking to classes compiled in a shared library.  I'd try making PongGame::onExit virtual to see if it is the compiler making a false assumption that the child class' method will be called.  When the shared library is build, your class didn't exist so maybe the dynamic linkage isn't getting updated correctly.  Just something to try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your run() method virtual in order to force your object pointer to be interpreted as a PongGame object since currently it is not. Some compilers may warn you to override run() as well. In that case, PongGame implementation of run() can be a simple code repetition which is harmless most of the time.

```
void PongGame::run() {
    SlimGame::run();
}
```